# Using 2 factor authentication syncing gmail contacts with evolution

Tags: sync, evolution, contacts, gmail

I have been trying to get an answer to a question but all I find are links to non related subjects or suggestions to try another method. So here goes:

Is is possible to get gmail contacts synchronised with Evolution in Ubuntu 12.04?

I have been able to get the email and calendar components set up very easily in a matter of seconds, the contact aspect though is proving more difficult.

The method I'm currently using is to:

- go to the contacts tab
- select new and then "addressbook" from the dropdown list
- select "google" from the options
- add in all the requested information and hit apply

It then throws a large red error banner:

"This address book cannot be opened.  This either means that an incorrect URI was entered, or the server is unreachable.

Detailed error message: This account requires an application-specific password. (http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056286)"

It never asks me for a password or provides a location for me to enter in the password required.

Has any one been able to get this working? If so what steps am I missing or performing incorrectly? Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Are you using application specific password?

Comment: Yes, that's why it keeps asking for it. It never provides a place to enter one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy fix.

1. open seahorse which is for some reason listed as "passwords and
   keys" in the  Ubuntu applications menu
2. open the Passwords tab
3. find the google:// entries for your google contacts
4. open that entry or entries and expand the password dropdown at the bottom
5. reset or enter your new password
6. rejoice in contacts sync

Comment: That isn't working for me, perhaps it's gotten a little confused with application specific passwords though. I might just go and revoke them all and start over.

Comment: I'd previously looked through seahorse to see if I could find a saved key that could have caused this issue. So this time I took a slash and burn approach and deleted all the keys associated with the account. Then, when reopening evolution it finally prompted me for a key when I went to the contacts again.